# cannot understand the head node

Tags: java, data-structures

```
 private class Node {
        E element;
        Node next;
        Node prev;

        public Node(E element, Node next, Node prev) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
    /**
     * returns the size of the linked list
     * @return
     */
    public int size() { return size; }

    /**
     * return whether the list is empty or not
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; }

    /**
     * adds element at the starting of the linked list
     * @param element
     */
    public void addFirst(E element) {
        Node tmp = new Node(element, head, null);
        if(head != null ) {head.prev = tmp;}
        head = tmp;
        if(tail == null) { tail = tmp;}
        size++;
        System.out.println("adding: "+element);
    }
```

- See more at: http://java2novice.com/data-structures-in-java/linked-list/doubly-linked-list/#sthash.CPsiWR4R.dpuf

for the doublylinklist using java in the `addFirst(E element)` method :

```
public void addFirst(E element) {
        Node tmp = new Node(element, head, null);
        if(head != null ) {head.prev = tmp;}
        head = tmp;
        if(tail == null) { tail = tmp;}
        size++;
        System.out.println("adding: "+element);
    }
```

how come `head!=null`. Since we have not added any element in the head note it's
default value should have been null.That is `head==null` when the first if statement is being checked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you may want to insert a Node at the head of a LinkedList data structure that is not empty.

For example, I may have a list with `{1, 2}` in it, and I want to insert the value `0` at position 0 in that list.  To do that, I would call `addFirst()` on a `Node` with the value `0` in it - and when I do this, `head` is not `null`.

Comment: i am a little confused that when for the first time i add element using  addFirst(E element)
The next step is :

Node tmp = new Node(element, head, null);
         After that if condition   is checked:
         if(head != null ) {head.prev = tmp;}
then  the code if(head!=null){head.prev = temp;} will be true
but we have still not initialised Node head.It is still null how come if(head!=null) is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addFirst(E element) {



        Node tmp = new Node(element, head, null);
        if(head != null ) {//if head is null don't go in this body
           head.prev = tmp;//that means there is no node so no prev.
}
// if there is head make new node to be prev of head which is doing in if block
        head = tmp;//it becomes the first node in that case
        if(tail == null) { tail = tmp;}
        size++;
        System.out.println("adding: "+element);
    }
```

**Edit:**
 now you are having problem in understanding how following line of code works

```
 Node tmp = new Node(element, head, null);
```

So here are two case when you are adding first node which is the only node in the linked list and other case when there is a linked list and you are adding new first node.

so lets see the second scenario where there is a linked list

 so for a new node you need to point its `next` to the `head` as the head of the previous linked list and because `head` is already present so you need to add a link from `head` to its `prev` which is `tmp`.

see this image[image]

now when in the first scenario where there is no head node already present so temp node will point to null(head) which is for general purposes did like that.
so here

```
Node tmp = new Node(element, head, null);
```

you are actually pass `Node(element, null, null)` for the first scenario.

hope now you understand why they are passing head for the first node too.

**Edit 2**

```
 public void addFirst(E element) {
        Node tmp = new Node(element, head, null);
        if(head != null ) {head.prev = tmp;
        System.out.println("its head");}
        if(head==null){System.out.println("its  not head");}
        head = tmp;
        if(tail == null) { tail = tmp;}
        size++;
        System.out.println("adding: "+element);
    }
```

if you will try this it will print "its not head" for first element.

So don't confuse there is nothing to be confused of. It is working fine.

Comment: i am a little confused that when for the first time i add element using  addFirst(E element)
The next step is :

Node tmp = new Node(element, head, null);
         After that if condition   is checked:
         if(head != null ) {head.prev = tmp;}
then  the code if(head!=null){head.prev = temp;} will be true
but we have still not initialised Node head.It is still null how come if(head!=null) is true.

Comment: for the first time the if condition is not getting true  if(head!=null){head.prev = temp;} you are mistaking that it is getting true when head is null it just bypass it and making head to temp.

Comment: public void addFirst(E element) {

        if(head==null)
        {
            System.out.println("head is nullllllllllllllllll");
          
        }
        Node tmp = new Node(element, head, null);
        if(head!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("head is not nullllllllllllllllll after tmp");
            System.out.println(head.element);
        }

        if(head != null ) {head.prev = tmp;}
        head = tmp;
        if(tail == null) { tail = tmp;}
        size++;
        System.out.println("adding: "+element);
    }

Comment: so it assigning head.prev to temp? use a print statement in that and then tell or just initialize head and tail to null where they are declared.

Comment: i have modified the method so as to check wheather it is bypassing or not and making head to temp.It is not bypassing if condition as from the above code in which  if(head==null) { System.out.println("head is nullllllllllllllllll"); } is printing the statement and if(head!=null) { System.out.println("head is not nullllllllllllllllll after tmp"); System.out.println(head.element); } is also true it is not bypassing anything.

Comment: yeah it is assigining head.prev to temp initially

Comment: thanks a lot Bro i got a little confused and assumed that head!=null for the first time now i can see that it is directly going to head=temp bypassing the if condition  thanks a lot!

Comment: if it has solved your problem then mark it answered :)